# How to save text field input as integer - Flutter and Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some code that will currently update my current user's firestore by saving the input of the text field:

```
RaisedButton(
                  elevation: 4,
                  color: Palette.lightGreen,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('UserNames')
                          .doc(uid)
                          .update({
                        "plastics": _plasticController.text,
                      });
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    } catch (e) {}
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Save',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
```

How can I save this as an integer value instead, as I wish to add to it whenever the user decides to input another value later on.

I also still want to have the ability to display the value in text, and I am unsure of how to accomplish this as well.  I know how to display String-based data, but not integers from the cloud.

Comment: I don't know flutter but in javascript you could just cast the input value w/c is a string to a integer with `+value` or `parseInt(value)` or `Number(value)` before processing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_plasticController.text` is a `String`. Please use `int.parse(_plasticController.text)` to get a `int`.

P.S. If you need int->String, use `your_int_value.toString()`.